# Google Maps API - Adding arbitrary data to Point in Data Layer

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

```
var schoolLayer = new google.maps.Data();
schoolLayer.setMap(map);
let latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(coords1, coords2);
let school = new google.maps.Data.Point(latLng);
schoolLayer.add({geometry: school});
```

I am building a school layer.  I am doing this by adding points to a data layer.  I added the points pretty easily.  My question is, how do I add arbitrary data to the point, such as the school's name?

I tried to do `schoolLayer.add({geometry: school, school_name: 'Hello Elementary School'})` but it does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the arbitrary data in the properties field of the feature.

```
let latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419);
let school = new google.maps.Data.Point(latLng);
schoolLayer.add({
  geometry: school,
  properties: {
    name: "school1"
  }
});
```

Then you can get it in an event listener like this:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(schoolLayer, 'click', function(e) {
  infowindow.setContent(e.feature.getProperty("name"));
  infowindow.setOptions({
    pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(0, -40)
  })
  infowindow.setPosition(e.latLng);
  infowindow.open(map);
})
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/hu7aoeh5/2/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

```js
function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var schoolLayer = new google.maps.Data();
  schoolLayer.setMap(map);
  let latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419);
  let school = new google.maps.Data.Point(latLng);
  schoolLayer.add({
    geometry: school,
    properties: {
      name: "school1"
    }
  });
  let latLng2 = new google.maps.LatLng(37.445, -122.145);
  let school2 = new google.maps.Data.Point(latLng2);
  schoolLayer.add({
    geometry: school2,
    properties: {
      name: "school2"
    }
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(schoolLayer, 'click', function(e) {
    infowindow.setContent(e.feature.getProperty("name"));
    infowindow.setOptions({
      pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(0, -40)
    })
    infowindow.setPosition(e.latLng);
    infowindow.open(map);
  })
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```